# How to redirect client's HTTP requests to HTTPS via API Gateway Apache APISIX?

Tags: api, api-gateway, apache-apisix

How can I redirect client HTTP requests to HTTPS when using Apache APISIX? Is there a more convenient way? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a built-in feature provided by Apache APISIX. You can learn it from the `redirect` plugin, see https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/plugins/redirect/ for more details.

The related field is `http_to_https`.